# Hololens 2 Video Stream to pc by USB

Tags: hololens

I'm trying to write a Unity application to stream a video from the HL 2 to my PC (and ideally back to the hololens) in realtime and then access these frames to do something with it.

Is there a way to send theses frames by USB to my PC?
Things like Mixed Reality-WebRTC didn't work somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HoloLens doesn’t support establish a TCP/IP connection over USB, and IPOverUSB is only intended for use by VS debugging or Device Portal.  All classes of USB-C devices HoloLens2 supports have been listed in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-connect-devices#hololens-2-connect-usb-c-devices.